# Why am I getting " Duplicate entry" errors when inserting the DISTINCT values into a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert the distinct values of one field of the table `requests` into the only field of the table `pastmonth`

```
CREATE TABLE `pastmonth` (
  `video_id` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`video_id`)
);

INSERT INTO pastmonth (video_id)
SELECT DISTINCT (video_id)
FROM requests
WHERE exec_datetime >= NOW() - 60*24*60*60;
```

However I get this error

```
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'abcde' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I don't believe there are duplicate entries for the value `abcde` in the table `requests` because the following query indicates there is only 1 entry with that but it should not matter if there was because I'm SELECTING the DISTINCT values anyways.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM requests WHERE video_id = 'abcde';

COUNT(*)
1
```

I have a non-unique index on `requests.video_id` but I think that is irrelevant to the problem I have.  Is it possible that I have a corrupt btree index?

**EDIT**

```
CREATE TABLE `requests` (
  `request_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `video_id` char(5) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `exec_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`request_id`),
  KEY `exec_datetime` (`exec_datetime`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Is past month empty? You show the create table but I can't tell if it is being done in the same execution.

Comment: The table is empty but it has been created.  I executed the commands in sequence one at a time.

Comment: yes, are you sure the table PastMonth is empty? or there is no duplication between your select distinct and existing data in pastmonth?

Comment: none of your video IDs have a lenght greater than 5-digits, right? theres no 'abcdef'?

Comment: @FrankThomas, good point, very like truncated data has duplication

Comment: `pastmonth` is empty, there's no data in it.  The video IDs are all <= 5 characters.  I wanted to enforce this point by saying the data type of the `video_id` field for the `requests` table is `CHAR(5)`.

Comment: you can select max(len(videoid) to double check

Comment: It may help to note the datatype of video_id field was at one point in time `VARCHAR(256)` but it is now `CHAR(11)`

Comment: Can you show the DDL for requests?

Comment: What is the result of select count(*) from requests where video_id ='abcde%'?

Comment: It's 1 as I mentioned in my original post.  I've included the edit for the DDL for requests.

Comment: SELECT MAX(LENGTH(video_id) )FROM requests; returns 5, I accidentally said it returns 11 before...

Comment: I typed and corrected the SQL above, wild card it and I bet you have more than one as FrankThomas stated.

Comment: How do I "wildcard it"? What should I do?

Comment: What is the result of select count(*) from requests where video_id ='abcde%' As FrankThomas pointed out and the DDL shows, it's likely there are extended strings that are getting truncated to the same value.

Comment: Run this `select count(*) from requests where video_id LIKE 'abcde%'`

Comment: it's 0.  Don't you mean `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM requests WHERE video_id LIKE 'abcde%'`?  That returns 1.  I believe there is a corrupt index, I guarantee you there is nothing longer than 5 characters as the data type is `CHAR(5)`

Comment: The requests table defines video_id as char(11) meaning that there can be more but if the query reveals only one then maybe it is the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `requests` table, the `video_id` field is defined as:

```
`video_id` char(5) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL,
```

But in the new table, it's defined as:

```
`video_id` char(5)
```

There might be a difference in character set and corresponding collation. Make sure both fields have exactly the same character set and collation.

Comment: My bad, both are `CHAR(5)` I incorrectly transcribed the length of the data type.  I correctly my DDL of the requests table so now it accurately reflects my situation

Comment: @user784637 Transcribed? What happened to the good old copy-paste? Well, there's a different character set, you could look into that.

Comment: Yeah it was the collation... it's binary for the `requests` table but I believe the default is case insensitive when creating a new table.